# With ipywidgets, how to close the tab containing the button that is pressed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

With Jupyter notebook and ipywidgets, I created a list of tabs, each tab contains a button.
I would like that when a button is pressed, it closes its tab, leaving the rest of the abs untouched.
I have tried the following but it does not work as the function close_on_click is always associated to the last tab.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
%matplotlib inline

tabs = []

for k in range(10):
    
    wg_name = widgets.Text(
        value=str(k),
        placeholder='Index',
        description='Name:',
        disabled=False
    )
    
    wg_close = widgets.Button(
        description='Close tab',
    )
        
    tabs.append(VBox(children=[wg_name, wg_delete]))

    @wg_close.on_click
    def close_on_click(b):
        tab[k].close()
        
main_tab = widgets.Tab(children=tabs)
for k in range(10):
    main_tab.set_title(k, str(k))
main_wg = VBox(children=[main_tab])

display(main_wg)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are closing tab[k], where k=9 since the loop has already finished when you call close_on_click. That's why only the *last tab* is closing.

To close the current tab you should use k = main_tab.selected_index like so:

```
    def close_on_click(b):
        tabs[main_tab.selected_index].close()
        tabs.pop(main_tab.selected_index)
```

This is closing the current tab and removing it from the list of tabs, so that the next index will be correct.